# Recieve components and there details dynamically and render them in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, native

I had a cordova-based e-commerce app that I want to convert to flutter.

In that app, for any page I used to send an ajax request to a corresponding PHP page and fetch all the HTML, CSS and Javascript for that page and insert it into the document body. This enabled me to apply any UI or functionality change immediately without rolling out an app update, just by changing the PHP page.

My question is, is the same way of working possible in Flutter ? And how to implement it ? Or is it simply a bad idea to build a constantly changing app in Flutter ?

Comment: not feature  but I believe it is possible to figure it out in dart..... in a custom way. so don't give up.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter does not allow any of this feature and there is no way you can push code to existing app without creating an update on playstore or appstore.

Comment: not feature  but I believe it is possible to figure it out in dart..... in a custom way.